# Execute script on remote machine which is not in windows domain?

Tags: windows, scripting, remote-access

Requirement:
As part of deployment procedure I have to execute scripts on target servers.

Problems:
I don't want to log-in into every server using RDP just to execute a script. Some servers are not part of the domain. IT doesn't allow using WinRM on non-domain servers.

Question:
Considering the fact that I have an account on target server, with needed permissions, how to safely execute my scripts there without compromising security of the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

psexec to execute remote commands.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

```
psexec \\computername -u user -p password ...
```

Username may need to be qualified with the computer name in front as in:

```
computername\username
```

Comment: I tried PsExec but couldn't make it work for non-domain machine :(

Comment: @Anil did you use the proper parameters? You may have to make the user qualified with the computer name in front like computer\user

Comment: This is what I do: `..\Tools\PsTools\PsExec.exe \\192.168.0.123 -u 192.168.0.123\MYUSER -p MYPASS cmd MD G:\Projects\DeploymentTempDir`, but I always get `Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.`

Comment: Kludgy, but... can you create a local account on the Win7 workstation and run PSexec as that account?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the sysinternals [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), it can run scripts against a list of computers.

I am also a fan of [SaltStack](http://www.saltstack.com/), the following in salt would run the 'ls' command on all minions:

```
salt '*' cmd.run 'ls'
```

Comment: I tried PsExec but couldn't make it work for non-domain machine :(

Comment: What version of windows are you running?  http://jamsignal.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-use-psexec-with-non-domain.html

Comment: My machine is Win7 Enterprise 64bit, and server is Win 2008 R2.